# jqGrid takes 30 seconds to count that i have 1.1 million rows in grid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a dataset that has about 1,100,000 rows.

When I load this into my jqGrid,  SQL Profiler tells me it takes 29.7 seconds just to return the count of records and then a further 29.8 seconds to return the data to display in the grid.

Please see below the SQL that does the row count against my SQL Server table.

```sql
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_ProductSearch_FULL] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Can anyone suggest how to improve the performance of this "count" query that is generated by jqGrid?

Comment: Do you really want to display the count or records and the cout of pages in the grid? If you do need it you should include code of the View `vw_ProductSearch_FULL`. The second question: why you need 29.8 seconds to return the data to display in the grid? Which method of data paging you use?

Comment: Look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8084466/315935) which describe shortly what one can do to eliminate the need to calculate the count of records.

Comment: You have a problem wich is not related to the grid, why you should show more than a million records in a view? You should use SQL pagination at least ... but i think you should carefully redisign your user interface concept.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information about your database in order to recommend improvements to your query. But as Oleg said, you may not need to query for the count.

As to the data in the grid, you have seen that having ~1 million rows in the grid just does not work well. I suggest you either use Pagination or True Scrolling Rows to only load a small subset of the rows at any given time. This should get your performance back up to an acceptable level.