# Why are 'next' pager buttons enabled initially?

Tags: jqgrid

Why are the pager buttons for `next` enabled by default for an empty grid as shown here:

[image]

Do I need to explicitly add `ui-state-disabled` class to disable them, after `gridComplete`?

*Version I am currently working on: 4.6.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the bug in old version of jqGrid which you use. The bug is fixed in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Comment: Where could I get the latest English version of `grid.locale-en.js`

Comment: @SuhailGupta `grid.locale-en.js` should correspond the version of jqGrid which you use? Which one you try to use?

Comment: I am using the version that came with `4.6`. When I load the grid with new css and grid js except the language file, I get [this error](http://s30.postimg.org/6kz8xiyzl/Capture.png)

Comment: @SuhailGupta: The error will be displayed by **free jqGrid** and not by jqGrid 4.6 if you use wrong language files (for example `grid.locale-en.js` from 4.6). You should either remove `grid.locale-en.js` (English locale is included in the main file `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`/`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) or to fix the code where you set jqGrid settings: you should search for `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, ...)` and replace it to correct code `$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, ...)` .

Comment: I got rid of the error but I see the buttons enabled in the [latest code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You should provide the demo which demonstrates the problem. I just modified some demo to  http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ex6158L1/11/ and I see no buttons enabled. If you can provide the demo which can I use to reproduce the bug I can fix it very easy and you can download the fixed version from GitHub.

Comment: I tried to reproduce by editing your fiddle, but the buttons are disabled. I have used [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) Could it be due to those files?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I though that I found the test case which you could had. I posted small changes to GitHub. Please reload your sources from https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid or retry with the URLs `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.cs`

Comment: So, we found a bug! It is disabled now. What was the issue?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I suppose that you used `datatype: "local"` and not `datatype: "json"` like in the previous example. After I could reproduce the problem I made [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/10df59ed1cc3ddca2e072792f3794067b7313c6e). Plase prepare always short demo if you reports some problem.

Comment: Alright. But I used `datatype:json`. Here is the [complete wrapper](http://pastebin.com/P9TJA7gg) I am using.